# MySQL Sub-Select Then Group Not Working

Tags: mysql

I have table structure like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_a` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `col_a_one` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `table_b` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `table_a_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_b_one` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_a_idx` (`table_a_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_a` FOREIGN KEY (`table_a_id`) REFERENCES `table_a` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

With this value:

```
INSERT INTO table_a VALUES (1, 'First Row');
INSERT INTO table_a VALUES (2, 'Second Row');

INSERT INTO table_b VALUES (1,1,'Jan 2017');
INSERT INTO table_b VALUES (2,1,'Feb 2017');
INSERT INTO table_b VALUES (3,2,'Jun 2018');
INSERT INTO table_b VALUES (4,2,'Jul 2018');
INSERT INTO table_b VALUES (5,1,'Mar 2017');
```

TABLE: table_a

```
id, col_a_one
1, First Row
2, Second Row
```

TABLE: table_b

```
id, table_a_id, col_b_one
1, 1, Jan 2017
2, 1, Feb 2017
3, 2, Jun 2018
4, 2, Jul 2018
5, 1, Mar 2017
```

In my computer, if i execute this query :

```
SELECT
    c.*
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        t1.`id` AS 'table_a_id',
        t2.`id` AS 'table_b_id',
        t1.`col_a_one`,
        t2.`col_b_one`,
        DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(t2.`col_b_one`, '%b %Y'), "%Y-%m-01") AS 'test_column'
    FROM `table_a` t1
         INNER JOIN `table_b` t2
            ON t1.`id` = t2.`table_a_id`
    ORDER BY
        t1.`id` ASC,
        DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(t2.`col_b_one`, '%b %Y'), "%Y-%m-01") DESC
) AS c
GROUP BY
    c.`table_a_id`
```

it will return wrong result :

```
table_a_id, table_b_id, col_a_one, col_b_one, test_column
1, 1, First Row, Jan 2017, 2017-01-01
2, 3, Second Row, Jun 2018, 2018-06-01
```

But if i execute in sqlfiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5a1f0/1 the results as I expected:

```
table_a_id, table_b_id, col_a_one, col_b_one, test_column
1, 5, First Row, Mar 2017, 2017-03-01
2, 4, Second Row, Jul 2018, 2018-07-01
```

I am using MySQL 5.7, this is sql_mode i used:

```
ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

What is wrong with my MySQL server...?

Comment: "What is wrong with my MySQL server...?" Nothing you are misusing MySQL GROUP BY feature and i don't believe your sql_mode is correct..  see this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5a1f0/7 this is what sql_mode `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is suppose to do and look like.. I have a feeling on your local pc you are using MariaDB (fork off MySQL) (Use `SELECT VERSION()` to check) which ignores ORDER BY (without using LIMIT) in subqeuries see source https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/why-is-order-by-in-a-from-subquery-ignored/

Comment: Thanks for answer Raymond, this is what i get when execute SELECT VERSION() : 5.7.18-log
When i execute new query using: 
SET SESSION sql_mode  = CONCAT(@@sql_mode, ',ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY');
MySQL show error:
Error Code: 1055. Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'c.table_b_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: why in my local pc ORDER DESC in sub select and then GROUP always return table_b_id = 1 for table_a_id = 1...?
this my query and the result alway use the oldest date, https://snag.gy/8gDbca.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit 2**

Based on further comments, this might be what you want. It selects all the values from `table_b` which correspond to the latest date in that table for each `table_a` row:

```
SELECT a.id AS table_a_id,
    a.col_a_one,
    DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(b1.col_b_one, '%b %Y'), "%b %Y") AS 'latest_date',
    COUNT(b.id) AS 'total_item_b',
    b1.col_b_two
FROM table_a a
JOIN table_b b ON b.table_a_id = a.id
JOIN table_b b1 ON b1.table_a_id = a.id AND
    STR_TO_DATE(b1.`col_b_one`, '%b %Y') = (SELECT MAX(STR_TO_DATE(`col_b_one`, '%b %Y'))
                                            FROM table_b
                                            WHERE table_b.table_a_id = a.id)
GROUP BY a.id
```

Output:

```
table_a_id  col_a_one   latest_date     total_item_b  col_b_two
1           First Row   Mar 2017        3             Y
2           Second Row  Jul 2018        2             M
```

Updated [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e403fd/26)

**Edit**

Based on comments below, I think this query is what you really want:

```
SELECT a.id AS table_a_id,
    a.col_a_one,
    DATE_FORMAT(MAX(STR_TO_DATE(b.col_b_one, '%b %Y')), "%b %Y") AS 'latest_date',
    COUNT(b.id) AS 'total_item_b'
FROM table_a a
JOIN table_b b ON b.table_a_id = a.id
GROUP BY a.id
```

This returns the count of items in `table_b` for each row in `table_a`, as well as the latest (newest) date:

```
table_a_id  col_a_one   latest_date     total_item_b
1           First Row   Mar 2017        3
2           Second Row  Jul 2018        2
```

Updated [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5a1f0/28)

As @RaymondNijland points out, you are not using `GROUP BY` correctly. When grouping, non-aggregated and non-grouped columns will return random values, this is why you are getting different results for everything not directly related to `table_a_id`. It looks like what you are trying to achieve is to return the value of `table_a_id` which has the maximum value of `col_b_one` for each `table_a_id` which you can do with this query:

```
SELECT 
    a.`id` AS 'table_a_id',
    b.`id` AS 'table_b_id',
    a.`col_a_one`,
    b.`col_b_one`
FROM `table_a` a
JOIN `table_b` b ON a.`id` = b.`table_a_id` AND
  STR_TO_DATE(b.`col_b_one`, '%b %Y') = (SELECT MAX(STR_TO_DATE(`col_b_one`, '%b %Y'))
                                         FROM table_b
                                         WHERE table_b.table_a_id = a.id)
ORDER BY a.id ASC
```

Output:

```
table_a_id  table_b_id  col_a_one   col_b_one
1           5           First Row   Mar 2017
2           4           Second Row  Jul 2018
```

I've updated your [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5a1f0/15) to demonstrate.

Comment: hi Nick, actually i want to get count of table_b row that match with table_a,
table_a item have many table_b items, so i will use grouping. Not Join.
i will add COUNT(c.`table_b_id`) AS 'total_item_b' in outer select, see my screen shoot: https://snag.gy/RtFeIz.jpg

Comment: @MohdErwin you need to update your question. Your original question does not mention any aggregate functions such as `COUNT`. But if you are grouping, why are trying to output the value of `table_b_id` as that will be meaningless?

Comment: This query is running well in sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5a1f0/16, but not in my local pc.
table_a_id 1 will always have col_b_one = Jan 2017.
I don't know why...

Comment: As I said in my answer, "non-aggregated and non-grouped columns will return random values"

Comment: yes Nick, table_b_id  is meaningless. i don't need it. but i just want to make sure which item in table_b that selected.

Comment: "non-aggregated and non-grouped columns will return random values",
but it use aggregate function COUNT Nick

Comment: Do you want the maximum value of `col_b_one`?

Comment: yes Nick, i want newest data from col_b_one, what shoud i do...?

Comment: See my edit. I think this query will do what you want. [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5a1f0/28)

Comment: yes Nick, it work.
If table_b have one more column named col_b_two (VARCHAR), i have updated sqlfiddle, how to add b.col_b_two to select query...?

Comment: Can you please post link to new SQLFiddle

Comment: how can we achieve it...?

Comment: What value of `col_b_two` do you want? The one which corresponds to the newest value of `col_b_one`?

Comment: yes nick, The one which corresponds to the newest value of col_b_one => `Mar 2017` is `Y`

Comment: See my new edit. Updated [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e403fd/26)

Comment: That's great. If you would mark the answer accepted (the tick under the up/down arrows) I would appreciate it.

Comment: earlier, I was looking for a way to accepting the answer on google.
again, thank you nick.

Comment: No worries. btw, often the best way to understand the query is to remove the `GROUP BY` and replace the `SELECT` with a `SELECT *` so you can see all the data that the query is producing. e.g. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e403fd/27